# Spring Data JPA @Query UPDATE not updating?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Controller :

```
    public CarModel updateCarParameters(@RequestBody CarModel carModel){
    CarModel updated = carService.updateCarParameters(carModel);
    return updated;
    }
```

Service :

```
 public CarModel updateCarParameters(CarModel carModel){
    // check if car exists and validate new updated params

    String brand = carModel.getCarBrand();
    int id = carModel.getCarId();

    System.out.println(brand + " " + id);
    int i = carRepository.updateCar(brand,  id);

    System.out.println("Records changed ? : " + i );
    return null;
}
```

I have an JSON:

```
  {
    "carId" : 4,
    "carBrand": "Mazda"
  }
```

update Query :

```
String UPDATE_CAR = " UPDATE car_info c SET c.car_brand = :brand WHERE c.car_id = :id";


@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = UPDATE_CAR, nativeQuery = true)
    int updateCar(@Param("brand") String brand, @Param("id") int id);
```

when im passing e.g. c.carBrand = 'Mazda' c.car_id = 8 it doesn't effect on database

it returning 
CONSOLE :

```
Mazda 8            < -- System.out.println() before executing statement
Hibernate:  UPDATE car_info c SET c.car_brand = ? WHERE c.car_id = ?  
Records changed ? : 0   < -- System.out.println() after executing statement
```

in MySQL query works fine:

```
UPDATE car_info c SET car_brand = 'Hello' WHERE car_id = 4;
```

[image]

Comment: cannot see any row with car_id=8. Is it present?

Comment: @dassum check out the 8th row in the now updated screenshot ;)

Comment: have you tried by removing  "clearAutomatically=true"?

Comment: can you try with @Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)

Comment: @Modifying   
@Modifying(flushAutomatically = true)
@Modifying(clearAutomatically = true)

none of this works, every time same zero result

Comment: Can you add your service and controller code snippet.

Comment: post updated Controller and Service added